# C++11 enum class: plus int failed to compile, why?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, enums, int

I've got a quick code piece:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
enum class A:int {
    u=1,
    v=2,
    w=3
};
template<A value>
int nextEnum(){
    return value+1;
}
int main() {
    nextEnum<A::u>();
    return 0;
}
```

It fails to compile:

```
clang++ testenum.cpp -std=c++11
testenum.cpp:10:17: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('A' and 'int')
    return value+1;
```

Well, I've declared A as "int" enum, why it fails to "+" with int? How to fix it?

Comment: The "inheritance" for enumerations is more for range and size, not for actual inheritance. Also, by using [*scoped enumerations*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations) the type-name `A` is *strongly typed*. It's not implicitly convertible to other integer types, you have to convert it *explicitly*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
int operator+(A a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

will fix this error ! Test passed on Windows VS2017

Answer (score 3):

An `enum class` cannot be converted implicitely to an integer. You have to use `static_cast`, for example:

```
template <A value>
A nextEnum() {
  return static_cast<A>(static_cast<int>(value) + 1);
}
```

Comment: In fact, the *whole point* of `enum class` is that it doesn't implicitly convert to and from `int`.  (Well, that and the fact the enumerations don't get injected into the containing namespace).

Answer (score 3):

Enum classes are strongly typed and are not implicitly cast to int. To do so you need to define a conversion to int or a '+' operator in your enum class.